# Can't establish connection with bloomberg

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I can't establish connection between Python Bloomberg API and the Bloomberg Terminal. My Bloomberg terminal's location is on the C: in `\AppData\Local`, and I have placed blpapi3_32.dll and blpapi3_64.dll files to DAPI.

However, when I run this example :

```
from xbbg import blp

blp.bdp(tickers='NVDA US Equity', flds=['Security_Name', 'GICS_Sector_Name'])
```

it says:

```
ConnectionError: Cannot connect to Bloomberg
```

Comment: Are you logged into the Bloomberg running on your PC?

Comment: yes, i am. I can use it with excel, but python xbbg shows:" ConnectionError: Cannot connect to Bloomberg". I am also using bloomberg anywhere terminal

Comment: Is bbcomm.exe running (you can check in the task manager)? If not you can start it manually or you could run the API Diagnostics tool which may fix the issue.